# unable to run app error while installing app to device Xcode 11.6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I am trying to run my app using Xcode 11.6 but I am constantly getting unable to install app error.

**The LOG for why its not able to install**

```
Unable to install "Scan Box"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a41a81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a45bf70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010faadf35 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a45bca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012a2d2e91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010fbe15d4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010fbe3216 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70fc991d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70fcab07 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70fd093e _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70fd140b _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70fdaf8c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7125a4f2 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff712594c3 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.16 (Build 20A5323l)
Xcode 11.6 (16141)
```

**Steps I have tried:**
.Clear Build Folder

.Unpair and Repair the device

.Uninstall and reinstall Xcode

.Delete and open the project file

.Tried changing the Workspace settings to legacy

.cleared derived data using devcleaner

.installed a new profile for the device

.restart both devices

.set Build Library for Distribution to YES

.create, download a new profile for iOS development deployment

.ensure frameworks are set to embed and sign

.I have a paid account

.tried changing the bundle id as well

Devices used:
iPhone SE(1st Gen)(iOS 14), iPhone 8(iOS 13.6), iPad Pro(4th Gen)(iPad OS 14) These devices were on the latest version and the software was not touched in any way for the past one week. I was using these devices up until yesterday when I started facing these issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to either remove the embed static framework(s) or make them dynamic to resolve this issue. I had a similar issue and this worked for me.